# Return the reference of Tkinter control variable

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, return, controls

I am not an experienced programmer so advance apologies if I am asking a basic question. I am using a for loop to print tkinter Entries and trying to return the reference of these Entries to the calling function. But when I try to get the text typed in the entry it always returns empty string? So my question is whether it is possible to return the reference of the control variable in python ? or I am using a wrong approach?

```
    def data_entry_txtfield(self,rn,cn,pu,pd):
        # Creates the Entry to enter data - rn is the row and cn is column 
        # pd and pu are padding up and padding down
        entry = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(self.inputlab,width=32,bg=entrycolor,textvariable=entry)
        entry.grid(column=cn,row=rn,pady=(pu,pd))
        return entry



    tbtlocationentry = self.data_entry_txtfield(9,4,0,12)
    text = tbtlocationentry.get()
    print(text)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in this code like the bottom line your using self.data_entry_txtfield to call the function but you dont need the self. unless your using in a class. Also the entry needs a variable name to be able to change stuff inside it. I've fixed some errors and here is the code

```
def data_entry_txtfield(self,rn,cn,pu,pd):
        # Creates the Entry to enter data - rn is the row and cn is column 
        # pd and pu are padding up and padding down
        entry = tk.StringVar()
        ety = tk.Entry(self.inputlab,width=32,bg=entrycolor,textvariable=entry)
        ety.grid(column=cn,row=rn,pady=(pu,pd))
        return entry



    tbtlocationentry = self.data_entry_txtfield(9,4,0,12)
    text = tbtlocationentry.get()
    print(text)
```

I've left in the self. because i'm assuming your using this inside a class